# Java major version check in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, regular-expression, java

I've just installed Kafka following tutorial. It doesn't start because of `sh` script error:

```
$ sudo kafka-server-start.sh /etc/kafka.properties
/opt/Kafka/kafka_2.12-1.1.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 252: [[: 10 2018-04-17: syntax error in expression (error token is "2018-04-17")
[0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/opt/Kafka/kafka_2.12-1.1.0/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

checking line 252:

```
if [[ "$JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION" -ge "9" ]] ; then
```

I've added `echo` to get more info:

```
JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version "([^.-]*).*"/\1/p')
echo "JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION: $JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION"
if [[ "$JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION" -ge "9" ]] ; then
```

output is changed with:

> JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION: 10 2018-04-17

my java:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
```

### Question

How I should change `JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version "([^.-]*).*"/\1/p')` to fix my Kafka starter?

Comment: When did Java jump from v1.x to v10.x?  OpenJDK on my host is still reporting `openjdk version "1.8.0_171"`.  Notably, _without_ a date after the version number in the output.

Comment: Probable simple change, add `| cut -d' ' -f1` after the sed command. Others can magic sed itself. Interesting that openjdk added additional information to the version line. As @DopeGhoti noted, 1.8 doesn't have the date on it. The release of Java 10, though, was early this year, so I'd expect some distributions to start picking it up.

Comment: @KevinO, please add answer, to make me vote it. You are great - thanks.

Comment: My version of this using Bash expansions is here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77210970/430139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to drop the date off the end by using `cut`. This approach would result in:

```
JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version "([^.-]*).*"/\1/p' | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

This approach splits on the space character (-d' ') and takes the first field. Based upon the input, that would drop the openjdk appended date.

Answer (score 1):

This works for older "1.x.y" format as well as newer "x.y" format:

```
java -version 2>&1 \
  | head -1 \
  | cut -d'"' -f2 \
  | sed 's/^1\.//' \
  | cut -d'.' -f1
```

Source: https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/get-java-version-string-via-shell-commands/